# Как правильно формировать сообщения об ошибке для пользователя?

Tags: исключения, обработка-ошибок

Здравствуйте, коллеги!
Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом, какими правилами вы пользуетесь когда формируете сообщение об ошибке для пользователя при написании ПО.
К примеру пользователь пытается что то загрузить из сети и положить результат в БД. Соответственно могут произойти ошибки как связанные с сетью, так и с БД. Т.е. я бы сказал пользователю следующее (к примеру):

- Не удалось загрузить список должностей: Нет доступа к сети Интернет
- Не удалось загрузить список должностей: Client error 404 not found
- Не    удалось загрузить список должностей: Server error 500
- Не удалось    загрузить список должностей: Ошибка записи в БД

P.S можно ли выводить сообщение из пойманого exception?

Спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Answer (score 6):

«Пишите приложение так, будто поддерживать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, знающий, где вы живёте» (с) не моя.

Пользователи бывают разные по квалификации, в организациях с вашим сообщением об ошибке будет работать минимум два человека — собственно, пользователь и сотрудник техподдержки, поэтому надо, чтобы сообщение было полезно им обоим (да и вам самим на этапе отладки). Посмотрите, как организован журнал сообщений в Windows — там есть краткое описание ошибки в одну строчку, которое показывается в списке, и подробное с кучей информации, понятной разве что разработчику.

И рекомендую почитать классическую статью Якоба Нильсена «[Правила написания сообщений об ошибках](http://www.webmascon.com/topics/development/12a.asp)» ([Jakob Nielsen, «Error Message Guidelines»](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/error-message-guidelines/)).

Answer (score 5):

Поставьте себя на место пользователя, который не знаком с программированием, Вам интересно читать "Client error 404 not found", "Server error 500"?

Для такого пользователя эти 504 Gateway Timeout, как абракадабра. Его по сути должно волновать, когда эта проблема будет устранена и как продолжить работать с вашей программой.

Так вот, предположим пропало соединение с базой данных, тогда пользователю надо вывести сообщение:

*"Операция сохранения данных завершилась неудачей в связи с техническими проблемами на нашей стороне. Попробуйте через несколько минут."*

Если у пользователя пропал интернет, тогда это немного другая ошибка и она должна показывать не только наличие того, что пропал интернет, но и краткую информацию, как эту проблему можно решить. Может быть его firewall заблокировал?

*"Мы заметили, что у Вас пропало соединение с интернетом. Работа в режиме Offline с нашей программой невозможна, проверьте соединение с интернетом. Если вы не наблюдаете проблем с открытием страниц в браузере, возможно, доступ к сети мог был заблокирован вашим антивирусным ПО для нашей программы и Вам требуется проверить правила"*

Также, можно внизу сделать вкладку "Системная информация" и туда сохранить информацию об ошибке, данные запроса и т.д. и написать пользователю:

*"Если данная проблема сохраняется в течении длительного времени, обратитесь в техническую поддержку с информацией из вкладки 'системная информация'"*

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки, связанные с загрузкой данных по сети, я разделяю на два типа:

1. Ошибки на стороне клиента (проблемы с интернетом).
2. Ошибки на стороне сервера (его неработоспособность).

В первом случае я говорю пользователю, что возникли проблемы с интернетом и прошу его проверить его подключение к сети.

Во втором случае я говорю, что у запрашиваемого сайта какие-то проблемы и прошу проверить его работоспособность в браузере.

По поводу вывода сообщения из пойманного исключения: нет, я считаю, что его показывать не нужно.

А вообще, вопрос довольно субъективный и сильно зависит от разрабатываемого приложения.