# "Что-то пошло не так" - как правильно информировать пользователя об ошибках

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, консоль, desktop

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с приложениями, в том числе от Microsoft, разработчики которых не утруждают себя сообщать пользователям, что же на самом деле произошло, и почему приложение поломалось.

Наример:

- "Что-то пошло не так"
- "Неизвестная/неопознанная ошибка"
- "Установка прервана"
- "Дальнейшая работа приложения невозможна"

И это не выдранные из контекста тексты, а полноценные сообщения, которые вы хотя-бы раз в жизни видели, ну разве что в конец еще "...попробуйте позднее" еще дописать можно. И больше ничего.

Так же здесь встречаются вопросы, в которых всё очень плохо с обработкой ошибок. Не технически, а именно логически. Ссылку на этот пост можно будет давать в помощь новичкам.

К примеру, возьмем для простоты консольное приложение, которое записывает файл.

```cs
// плохой код
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите имя файла для записи: ");
    string path = Console.ReadLine();
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine("Файл записан!");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Что-то пошло не так!");
    }
}
```

Ответом можно описать, на ваше усмотрение:

- каким способом сообщить пользователю об ошибках: интерфейс, логи, другие способы.
- логические типы ошибок: фатальные и т.д.
- что надо положить в текст ошибок: где нужен стектрейс, где не нужен.

В целом, нужен ответ на вопрос: **Что делать с исключениями новичку-разработчику десктопного приложения, чтобы пользователь не растерялся при его возникновении?**

*(самоответа не будет, у меня тоже с этим плохо)*

---

- Связанный вопрос: [Как правильно формировать сообщения об ошибке для пользователя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/562279/373567)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор стоит вести [в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128931/discussion-on-question-by-aepot--------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для простых программ - можно сделать самоочищающееся окно лога, которое находится где-нибудь в настройках. Оптимизировать можно StringBuilder'ом и выводить только по открытию.

Для сложных коммерческих программ (или программ для "шарящих" пользователей) окно лога должно быть под рукой, возможно на какой-нибудь вкладке или по кнопке в отдельном окне. Да и MessageBox'ы для серьёзных ошибок никто не отменял.

Приличная доля пользователей не являются безмозглыми юзверями и в случае какой-нибудь проблемы они способны увидеть последнюю строчку в окне лога, да и техподдержка и администраторы, сопровождающие вашу программу будут вам петь оды, ибо не раз такое бывало, что какая-нибудь важная программа имеет бедный интерфейс и почти не ведёт лог-файлы, а потом из-за того, что часть пользователей не может к ней подключиться - пол-организации в простое, и главный админ не может разобраться что не так. Сотни/тысячи человеко-часов в день улетает в трубу, т.к. у программы нет тупого Multiline-MessageBox'а, который бы тупо выводил лог подключений.
Это пример из жизни.

Чем больше сообщений в окне лога - тем лучше (опять-же не конечному юзверю, а тому, кто потом будет разбираться с проблемами, и они точно будут, те или иные), если будет слишком много - уровни логирования.
Что касается stack-trace, если приложение в debug-режиме - то его можно и в лог интерфейса выводить.
В обещем в лог интерфейса всё, даже успешные действия.

Касательно лог файлов - туда только проблемы и процедуры запуска (чутка телеметрии не повредит), причём проблемы те, которые которые не являются внутренними проблемами, а касаются взаимодействия с внешними интерфейсами: tcp/udp подключения, запреты доступа к файлам, некорректный ввод данных, итд...

Там, где вы явно ловите ожидаемую ошибку в try-catch (например сервер недоступен) - выводите ошибку пользователю, с возможными вариантами решения, где предполагаете что может быть ошибка но по туче неизвестных причин - дополнительно stack-trace в лог-файл.

К другим способам - syslog сервер.
Ещё как вариант - дочерний процесс, который получает подробный лог от родителя (пайпы), и в случае краша родителя - выводит и логгирует в файл журнал последних действий/ошибок. Сейчас у этого подхода может есть более продвинутые альтернативы.

Если в кратце - ошибки, мешающие работе, выводить нужно всегда.
Т.к. когда у пользователя (к коим относятся и техподдержка с админами) проблемы, он действует по следующему алгоритму:

0. Что-то делать с программой
1. Ой, что-то не так
2. Какая-то ошибка
3. В чём проблема? Какова причина?
4. Как сделать так чтоб заработало?
5. Исправить и вернуться к пункту 0
6. Если не получается - искать информацию на стороне: инете/у техподдержки/админа
7. Если найдена информация в инете - к пункту 5, если обращение к ответственному лицу (условно техподдержка), способному решить проблему.
8. Техподдержка повторяет все предыдущие действия, но вместе с тем, чтобы лезть в инет он может заглянуть в собственные инструкции (любимые всеми скрипты техподдержки с финальной фразой: "перестанавите шиндовс, перезагрузите роутер")
9. Если пользователь обычный смертный человек - на него кладётся болт, и он либо лезет дальше штрудировать инет в поисках решения (если навыки позволяют) и скорее в конечном итоге забивает на вашу программу. Если же пользователь корпорат и техподдержка обязана решить проблему - заводится тикет и проблему уже решают более квалифицированные люди.
10. Далее снова воссоздаётся порядок действий, люди пытаются решить проблему, лезут в инет и в последствии связываются с теми, кто продал/написал программу тем или иным способом.

На пунктах 0-3 - всё просто в интерфейсе.
3-5 - достаточно messagebox.
4-9 - смотрят активный лог.
6-9 - если пользователь не юзверь, а вполне себе энтузиаст с навыками он тут уже читает лог файл и выискивает что на каком этапе неправильно работает, и тут уже нужны какие-то подробные инструкции с потенциальным списком проблем с возможными путями решений. Может доходить до банального, например, если ваше приложение сервер и к нему нет коннекта - в инструкциях должен быть вариант: "Не забудьте пробросить порты в роутере, добавьте в исключения файрвола/антивируса".
9-10 - тут уже лог файл, который будут слать вам. (про дампы ничего не скажу, не мой уровень)
И вишенка на торте №11 - `если с ходу не разберётесь, то придётся выкатывать обновления исключительно для того, чтобы программа писала дополнительную инфу (с стектрейсами и свойствами классов) в лог файл. Более того, придётся это делать для старой версии, которая официально более не поддерживается, но т.к. её купили и ей пользуются...`

Более подробно можно будет сказать только основываясь на данных о назначении программы и на кого она будет ориентирована.

Если просят вылизанную сложную программу, где бы пользователь не видел информации об ошибках и ему не требовалось что-либо самому решать и всё это оффлайн без регистрации и СМС, то нужно одно из двух: армия техподдержки или плевок этому недоделанному постановщику задачи. Чаще всего это манагер, который кроме айфона ничем не пользовался, и при первой-же попытке неправильно введённого пароля бежит требовать в техподдержку (чтобы у него всё "заработало"), рыдать к админам, и поносить программеров...

Хорошая программа - не та, что прячет ошибки под вылизанным интерфейсом, а та что даёт больше возможностей для их решения (чем удобнее - тем лучше). Проблемы были, есть и будут всегда и везде. Главное чтобы была возможность их решения. В конечном итоге выбираются те программы, где проблему можно решить самостоятельно, чем те, где ждёшь неделю в ожидании пока тикет дойдёт в очереди до нужного человека, чтобы он сказал переставить винду.

И в ответ на вопрос:
`Что делать с исключениями новичку-разработчику десктопного приложения, чтобы пользователь не растерялся при его возникновении?`
Я бы сказал следующее: если хотите чтобы пользователь мог решить проблему сам (если это не баг в коде конечно, а проблемы с внешними ресурсами), больше проверок - лучше, например: "сервер недоступен, порт занят, файл повреждён, итд...", должными не выпрыгивать стектрейсами, а проверяться до их возникновения, с более подробной информацией в окне лога, даже когда всё ок, например "подключение успешно, файл (url) скачан с сервера за T секунд, формат .***, дескриптор открыт/закрыт, файл (C:\**1) чтение, файл (C:\**2) чтение, файл (C:\**3) чтение".

Что-то меня понесло, т.к. наболело что как прогера, когда хочется сказать "ну вот смотри последнюю строчку в лог-окне, спецом же для тебя вынес", как и админа, когда программа никак не информирует, а чинить надо т.к. люди работают, и как юзера, когда и сам для себя хочу решить проблему, а приложение - чёрный ящик. Надеюсь что не напорол чуши.

Comment: Отличный ответ. У меня только личная просьба структурировать и оформить его красиво. Скажем так, для будущих поколений. Вопрос, который волновал меня, решён. У меня как бы были подозрения, что оно так и устроено, но теперь оно собралось в нормальное представление о проблеме и ее решении, спасибо!

Comment: @aepot я не мастер писать красивые мемуары, поэтому сделал ответ общим, если кто-то видит недостаток - может исправить.

Comment: черт, зачем? Назад теперь не сделать. И репутация мимо пойдет. Редактировать пост и без этого можно. Ну да ладно.

Comment: @aepot Я не в курсе нюансов функционирования ресурса, да и как-то не за рейтингом я здесь.

Answer (score 3):

> Постоянно сталкиваюсь с приложениями, в том числе от Microsoft, разработчики которых не утруждают себя сообщать пользователям, что же на самом деле произошло, и почему приложение поломалось.

На мой взгляд, это неправильно, но тем не менее, я могу понять, почему это делается. Если сообщение об ошибке выводится пользователю, следует озаботиться тем, чтобы оно было ему понятным: переведено на тот язык, на котором он говорит, объясняло все в терминах, понятных простому пользователю и т.д. При типичном `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` это все обычно не соблюдается. Поэтому логичное решение - просто наплевать на это, заменив сообщение на бессмысленное, и рекомендовать опытным пользователям копаться в логах, если их очень интересует настоящее сообщение об ошибке.

Другой причиной может быть бизнес-модель. Если программа бесплатная или дешевая, а основной доход разработчик получает от платной поддержки, разработчику выгоднее не предоставлять пользователю информацию для самостоятельного решения проблемы, а вывести безликий код ошибки и предложить обратиться в поддержку.

Если вы не Microsoft, рекомендую все же не следовать этому подходу, мой поход см. ниже.

> ```
> catch
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("Что-то пошло не так!");
> }
> ```

Это почти всегда анти-паттерн. Игнорировать исключения можно, но в этом случае ничего и на экран выводить не надо, если оно ожидаемое. Когда же что-то по настоящему "пошло не так", надо хотя бы логировать.

> каким способом сообщить пользователю об ошибках: интерфейс, логи, другие способы.

- В интерфейсе вывести сообщение вида `"Произошла ошибка: "+ex.GetType().ToString()+ex.Message`.
- В логи записать полный вывод `ex.ToString()` (т.е, со стеком).
- Через телеметрию, если она есть, также отправить на сервер полный вывод `ex.ToString()`.

При таком подходе есть некий риск, что пользователь не поймет информацию, которая выведена на экран, но по мне лучше принять это, чем вставлять палки в колеса пользователю, скрывая информацию. В отличие от веб-приложений, в настольных нет риска случайной выдачи секретных данных, так как программа работает только с теми данными, которые пользователю и так доступны.

Если пользователь - программист, можно и на экран выводить стек вызовов, только не в стандартный MessageBox, а сделать свой, где стек вынесен в отдельное поле с прокруткой - как-то так:

[image]

> логические типы ошибок: фатальные и т.д.

Не вижу смысла делить на фатальные и не фатальные. По настоящему фатальные, вроде Access Violation, все равно и обработать стандартными средствами не получиться. Все остальные обрабатывать нужно, даже те, которые являются следствием бага. Доводить до падения процесса и стандартного диалога "Отправьте в Microsoft..." из-за необработанного NRE **строго** не рекомендуется. В этом случае все несохраненные данные пользователя будут потеряны, что сильно перевешивает теоретический риск повреждения данных при продолжении работы с багом. А от отправки в Microsoft все равно толку ноль, ибо им до лампочки баги в наших поделиях.

**Внимание!** Раз на вопросе метка desktop, все рекомендации только для настольных приложений. Для веб приложений подход должен быть абсолютно другим.

Comment: Отправить в Microsoft - это, на самом деле, отправить разработчикам через сервис https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/windows-error-reporting. Вы, как разработчик, можете получать эти репорты. Так что это не Microsoft до лампочки, это разработчикам до лампочки, если они не знают, что эти отчеты можно получить.

Comment: Когда логи пишутся - хорошо. Но описанная проблема не только в то что на экране "Ой", а в логах стектрейсы. Проблема - это когда на экране "Ой" и в логах тоже "Ой", и больше ничего. Я не говорю про Windows или dotnet/runtime, но в проектах помельче оно встречается. Спасибо за ответ, противоречий нет.

Comment: Кстати, да, если пользователь прошаренный - стек вызовов может помочь самостоятельно решить проблему. Если например видит в стеке, например, условную последовательность: -> LoadMap() -> FileOpen()
 Не везде можно впихнуть ручной разбор ошибок на всевозможные ситуации с кастомными Exception'ами, очень трудозатратно (имхо)

Comment: _тот язык, на котором он говорит_ - это один из ключевых моментов. Сам собирался об этом написать, но хорошо, что это уже написано. Нужно изначально позаботиться о глобализации приложения, чтобы потом было легко делать его локализацию (в том числе сообщения об ошибках). [Globalize and localize .NET applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-and-localization)